# Formula to calculate days by month between two dates for future periods only

Tags: excel-formula

Struggling to come up with a formula that works for this (Data in A1 - E4)

```
StartDate   EndDate Jan Feb Mar
12/4/2018   4/20/2019   31  28  31
9/26/2018   1/30/2019   30  0   0
1/1/2019    3/31/2019   31  28  31
1/1/2015    3/31/2019   155 141 155
```

IN Cell C2, formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),B2))),"mmm")=C$1))
```

What I am trying to do is exclude past dates from the sum, for example in the 4th row, the Jan/Feb/Mar should be 31/28/31 and not count previous years.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you exclude past dates, today being the 2nd, would you not only have 30 for Jan or are you just wanting to exclude past years?

Comment: hi there, need to include all date ranges (some started a long time ago but continue well into the future, so only want to count ones in current year. I am needing to get 'days left' by month for 2019, so it's key to exclude the previous years from the count.

Comment: Okay, now that is different, you say future dates which would include other years after this one, or do you only want this year?

Comment: thanks!! appreciate the speedy help. Only needed current year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a chck for the year:

```
(YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))))=YEAR(TODAY()))
```

and just multiply them in the SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))))>=YEAR(TODAY()))*(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))),"mmm")=C$1))
```

[image]

---

One Note:

INDIRECT is Volatile and will re-calc each time Excel re-calcs.  I prefer to replace them with INDEX:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$A2) :INDEX($A:$A, IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))))>=YEAR(TODAY()))*(TEXT(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$A2) :INDEX($A:$A, IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))),"mmm")=C$1))
```